# What Time Zone is Tiny Death Star set in?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

Does anyone know what time of day the new levels appear each Monday now? it's currently 01:41 here in the UK on GMT and the levels are still locked, is there a specific time zone for the game at all?

Answer (score 1):

It is set in the time zone in which you are currently located.  For whatever reason, the new levels never seem to show up for anyone on Monday.  Rather, they seem to appear early Tuesday or perhaps late night on Monday.

This does not seem to conform to UTC or any other standard time zone that I have seen.

Comment: Just had the 4.4.2 android update for my HTC One phone and upon starting up Tiny Death Star again I got the message saying new levels were available so after attending all the usual stocking and ordering I went to go build the new levels but alas, still no new levels, they still show as locked in the list as well, no ideas now.

Comment: Look tomorrow.  It is currently Monday evening in your time zone.  If you read my answer, they show up on Tuesday for whatever reason.

Comment: I just got 4 new levels. Residential, recreation and 2 x imperial

Answer (score 0):

It's tuesday morning here in Australia, so after also doing startup maintenance, I went to select some new levels

Had about 5M credits, and also having two Recruitment Officers saved, and 2 Endor bitizens and 2 of the new retail bitizens doing other chores, decided on a new apartment and a recreational level. So it may seem that either it waits for Tuesday, or mid morning in the USA ?

All seemed fine until I noticed both new levels are FOODs. Confirmed when I went into ALBUM > LEVELS > FOOD. I have 13/11 !!!!

Very weird

90mins or so later... back to do more general maintenance and the levels building are correct in their type. Phew